# "Are the same person" or "Is the same person"?

Tags: grammaticality, singular-vs-plural

> 1. **Father's grandfather** and **grandfather's father** are the same person.
> 2. **Father's grandfather** and **grandfather's father** is the same person.
> 3. **Father's grandfather** and **grandfather's father** are the same people.

Which one is correct? I guess that the second sentence is right because there is actually one person- singular not plural. Am I right ?

Comment: There are two roles, so "are", and one physical player of those roles, so "the same person".

Comment: @StoneyB : you mean the first one ?

Comment: @StoneyB: It might often sound a *little* bit awkward, but I don't think constructions like [*Peter Parker and Spider-man **is** the same person*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Peter+Parker+and+Spider-man+is+the+same+person%22) are inherently "ungrammatical". Since the *semantics* of these rather unusual statements specifically tell us that there is in fact only "one" person being referenced, I think the plurality of the verb form is somewhat open to question (or stylistic choice, if you like).

Comment: To this native speaker, it *has* to be **are**.  "X and Y **are** something", never "X and Y **is** something."

Comment: @stangdon ... except in the case of conjunct names (*Barnes and Noble is closing Nook Video*) and conjuncts denoting entities 'merged' in a single substance (*Bread and jam is my favorite snack*). But in this case *Peter Parker* and *Spiderman* are presented as distinct entities: if they were a 'merged' entity you could not compare them as *the same*.

Comment: @StoneyB - Good point.  OK, if X and Y are separate entities, they have to be "are"; singular entities get "is".

Comment: @DavidC No, I mean the first: *A and B are the same C*.

Comment: @StoneyB I must have been looking at it cross-eyed. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is correct as although "father's grandfather" and "grandfather's father" are referring to the same person but at the time of speaking/referring, they are the instances of a singleton personality.

Further, the  grandfather's father instance is older than father's grandfather( considering the natural timeline). Thus, due to different instances of the same person for two different perspectives, "is" can't be used in this context.